# What is more efficient "||" or a loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, performance

Let just say you have to edit a series of words from an arraylist("cat", "dog", "catdog", "mandog")

Now you can either put it into a for loop like so

```
 for(int i=0; i<arraylist.size(); i++){
    if(arraylist.get(i).matches("cat") || arraylist.get(i).matches("dog") etc.. etc..
      {
        //do something
      }
   }
```

Or you can put the words(cat, dog, catdog and mandog) into a string array/arraylist and compare them using that.

Which one is more efficient?

Taking into consideration that the list of words could be pretty big.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: More efficient is to pull the `arrayList.get(i)` operation out of the if, so it only gets evaluated once.

Comment: I doubt it will make that much of a difference. Code readability is more important here: you don't want a giant if statement that explicitly compares .get(i) with every word

Comment: Neither. Put the words in a set and see if `arraylist.get(i)` is in the set.

Comment: Also, using `matches()` when not actually using a regex is not the wiseest thing to do, too.

Comment: What is the type of operation you want to do with those strings ?

Answer (score 4):

Neither, performance difference will be negligible, both of them are linear in time in the size of the keywords list.

Considering the list of words could become pretty big, you should use a `Set`. A [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) can perform a `contains` check in constant time, making it very suitable for this purpose. So:

```
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>();

keywords.add("cat");
keywords.add("dog");
// ...

for (String element: arraylist) {
    if (keywords.contains(element)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Note that using `matches` as you do is actually the same as using `equals`, so we can simply test for equality.

Comment: HashSet is the best way to verify if element contains or not and it's done in constant time. Notice that the contains method is case sensitive and it will not work if you want to compare with the string "Cat" from the given sample code, then it's good idea do add a lowercase keyword and compare only in lowercase mode, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the appropriate way (although alot more work) is to test all the options. Use a profiler to see how much time it takes your code to perform the lookups and then go with the process that yields the best results.

Without using a profiler, it is very hard to determine improvements in performance.

Comment: Not always. If you can replace a data structure with another one in a better time complexity class for the operations you need (e.g. HashSet vs. ArrayList for containment), you will almost certainly introduce a performance improvement.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, you are correct. That is also a great way to ensure performance improvements in code.  However, it would still be hard for you to objectively determine the changes improved the code without some way to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `matches()` method in your code I assume you need to do a match against a regex. If that is the case you could go for a nested for-loop.

```
String[] patterns = {"cat", "dog"};
for(String item : arraylist){
    for(String pattern : patterns){
        if(item.matches(pattern)){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to check whether the string is present in the list you could go with Stefano Sanfilippo approach.

Comment: No need to wrap the `patterns` array in a list, you can iterate on arrays as well.

Comment: Yes. Sorry that was just my common coding style.. Edited.. :)

Comment: If both the arraylist and the group of patterns have many entries you might combine the patterns programmatically (using parens and `|`) into a single pattern, compile this once and then match against all items of the arraylist. But it seems "matches" wasn't really necessary.